# C / C++ MultiDimensional Array Internals

Tags: c

I have a question about how C / C++ internally stores multidimensional arrays declared using the notation `foo[m][n]`.  I am not questioning pure pointers to pointers etc...  I am asking because of speed reasons...

Correct me if I am wrong, but syntactically `foo` is an array of pointers, which themselves point to an array

```
int foo[5][4]
*(foo + i)           // returns a memory address
*( *(foo + i) + j)    // returns an int
```

I have heard from many places that the C/C++ compiler converts `foo[m][n]` to a one dimensional array behind the scenes (calculating the required one dimension index with `i * width + j`).  However if this was true then the following would hold

```
*(foo + 1)          // should return element foo[0][1]
```

Thus my question:
Is it true that `foo[m][n]` is (always?) stored in memory as a flat one dimensional array??  If so, why does the above code work as shown.

Comment: In case others have the same question, here is some further info:  
    `*foo == foo[0] == &foo[0][0]`  
    `*(foo+1) == foo[1] == &foo[1][0]`  
    `(int *)foo + 1 == &foo[0][1]`

Comment: No, `foo` is not an array of pointers; it's an array of arrays.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, C/C++ stores a multi-dimensional (rectangular) array as a contiguous memory area. But, your syntax is incorrect. To modify element `foo[0][1]`, the following code will work:

```
*((int *)foo+1)=5;
```

The explicit cast is necessary, because `foo+1`, is the same as `&foo[1]` which is not at all the same thing as `foo[0][1]`. `*(foo+1)` is a pointer to the fifth element in the flat memory area. In other words, `*(foo+1)` is basically `foo[1]` and `**(foo+1)` is `foo[1][0]`. Here is how the memory is laid out for some of your two dimensional array:

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that that *will* work, but IF foo was just a flat 1D array (of say ints), then you shouldn't be able to dereference twice - there shouldn't even be 2 pointers!!!!

Comment: @Arrakis, but it isn't a flat 1D array to the compiler, it is a 2D array. It just so happens that the 2D array is laid out in memory in the same way as a 1D array of size product of the two dimensions would be.

Comment: There are two pointers because you asked for two by creating a multi-dimensional array.  How it's stored in memory has no bearing on how it's referenced from the code.

Comment: Right, so in code I created an array of pointers to an array of ints.

In memory, it's just a single array of ints.  However this structure is completely hidden from the code perspective???

Comment: Hidden until you do as @MichaelGoldshteyn said above, and explicitly cast as an `int*` instead of `int **`

Comment: No, there is not pointer to pointer, either stored in memory or as part of any valid expression here.

Comment: No cast is necessary.  `foo[1][0]` is `*(*(foo + 1) + 0)`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, yes that is correct; however, that requires two dereferences while the cast requires just one. Of course, a good compiler will optimize yours to just one, but at -O0 this answer is more efficient than yours.

Comment: I take that back-- gcc version 4.9.2, even on -O0, compiles both of those code snippets to the exact same code (which, incidentally, uses more instructions than the code that just uses the normal brackets)

Answer (score 31):

A two-dimensional array:

```
int foo[5][4];
```

is nothing more or less than an array of arrays:

```
typedef int row[4];   /* type "row" is an array of 4 ints */
row foo[5];           /* the object "foo" is an array of 5 rows */
```

*There are no pointer objects here, either explicit or implicit.*

Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

What often causes confusion is that an array *expression* is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.  (And a separate rule says that what looks like an array parameter declaration is really a pointer declaration, but that doesn't apply in this example.)  An array *object* is an array object; declaring such an object does not create any pointer objects.  Referring to an array object can create a pointer *value* (the address of the array's first element), but there is no pointer object stored in memory.

The array object `foo` is stored in memory as 5 contiguous elements, where each element is itself an array of 4 contiguous `int` elements; the whole thing is therefore stored as 20 contiguous `int` objects.

The indexing operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic; `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x + y)`.  Typically the left operand is going to be either a pointer expression *or* an array expression; if it's an array expression, the array is implicitly converted to a pointer.

So `foo[x][y]` is equivalent to `*(foo[x] + y)`, which in turn is equivalent to `*(*(foo + x) + y)`.  (Note that no casts are necessary.)  Fortunately, you don't have to write it that way, and `foo[x][y]` is a lot easier to understand.

Note that you *can* create a data structure that can be accessed with the same `foo[x][y]` syntax, but where `foo` really is a pointer to pointer to int.  (In that case, the prefix of each `[]` operator is already a pointer expression, and doesn't need to be converted.)  But to do that, you'd have to declare `foo` as a pointer-to-pointer-to-int:

```
int **foo;
```

and then allocate and initialize all the necessary memory.  This is more flexible than `int foo[5][4]`, since you can determine the number of rows and the size (or even existence) of each row dynamically.

Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) explains this very well.

**EDIT:**

In response to Arrakis's comment, it's important to keep in mind the distinction between *type* and *representation*.

For example, these two types:

```
struct pair { int x; int y;};
typedef int arr2[2];
```

very likely have the same representation in memory (two consecutive `int` objects), but the syntax to access the elements is quite different.

Similarly, the types `int[5][4]` and `int[20]` have the same memory layout (20 consecutive `int` objects), but the syntax to access the elements is different.

You *can* access `foo[2][2]` as `((int*)foo)[10]` (treating the 2-dimensional array as if it were a 1-dimensional array).  And sometimes it's useful to do so, but strictly speaking the behavior is undefined.  You can likely get away with it because most C implementations don't do array bounds-checking. On the other hand, optimizing compilers can *assume* that your code's behavior is defined, and generate arbitrary code if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My initial problem was in the fact that  
`foo[5][4]` in memory is a 1D array - not 2D.  I was thus confused about why `*(*(foo + 1) +2)` would give a numeric value, as that is 2 dereferences (obviously invalid in a 1D array).  My understanding now is that the code presents this array of array notation even though it's not what happens underneath.  Casting to `(int *) foo` thus exposes the real memory structure of `foo`

Comment: I'm confused about the same thing @Arrakis is.  I understand the difference now.  The distinction is slight, but highly dangerous if misunderstood.  w

Comment: I had the same question as @Arrakis, but I figured it out.  Because it's a fixed array, the compiler knows the number of bytes between `foo[0][0]` and `foo[1][0]`.  Likely in the same way it knows to add different values to a long* vs. an int*.  From the link, I think this should work `int* bar=foo[1]`, while it's very sensible that `int **bar=foo` should not.  In almost all cases int[][] and int ** function the same way, but the differences are extremely important if you want to mix and match.  This was a serious tangent, but you've seriously earned your +1 @KeithThompson

Comment: @Kendrick: I wouldn't say that `int[][]` and `int**` *function* the same way.  The implicit decay of array expressions to pointers causes them to *appear* to behave similarly, but the underlying behavior is quite different.

Comment: Sir I do not understand the last statement: *You can probably get away with it because most C implementations don't do array bounds-checking.* What if I forced compiler to check array bound?

Comment: @haccks: How would you "force" a compiler to check array bounds?

Comment: Hmm. First tell me about behavior of this code `#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5][5];
 int *p;
 
    for(p = &a[0][0]; p <= &a[4][4]; p++)
  *p = 0;
    return 0;
}`. Is it cause UB?

Comment: @haccks: Yes, that has undefined beahvior. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). The rule is stated in 6.5.6p8: "... otherwise, the behavior is undefined", confirmed in Annex J section 2: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int
a[4][5]`) (6.5.6).

Comment: In the code I have given , I see that `*p` is evaluated in the array bound and it should not invoke UB ( what I understand by reading this in Annex J section 2: *Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
integer type produces a result that points just beyond the array object and is used as
the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated (6.5.6).* or I think I misunderstood something.

Comment: @haccks: The relevant array object is a single row of the 2D array. There is no 25-element array of `int`, only a 5-element array of `int[5]` elements.

Answer (score 7):

C arrays - even multi-dimensional ones - are contiguous, ie an array of type `int [4][5]` is structurally equivalent to an array of type `int [20]`.

However, these types are still incompatible according to C language semantics. In particular, the following code is in violation of the C standard:

```
int foo[4][5] = { { 0 } };
int *p = &foo[0][0];
int x = p[12]; // undefined behaviour - can't treat foo as int [20]
```

The reason for this is that the C standard is (probably intentionally) worded in a way which makes bounds-checking implementations possible: As `p` is derived from `foo[0]`, which has type `int [5]`, valid indices must be in range `0..5` (resp. `0..4` if you actually access the element).

Many other programming languages (Java, Perl, Python, JavaScript, ...) use jagged arrays to implement multi-dimensional arrays. This is also possible in C by using an array of pointers:

```
int *bar[4] = { NULL };
bar[0] = (int [3]){ 0 };
bar[1] = (int [5]){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int y = bar[1][2]; // y == 3
```

However, jagged arrays are not contiguous, and the pointed-to arrays need not be of uniform size.

Because of implicit conversion of array expressions into pointer expressions, indexing jagged and non-jagged arrays looks identical, but the actual address calculations will be quite different:

```
&foo[1]    == (int (*)[5])((char *)&foo + 1 * sizeof (int [5]))

&bar[1]    == (int **)((char *)&bar + 1 * sizeof (int *))

&foo[1][2] == (int *)((char *)&foo[1] + 2 * sizeof (int))
           == (int *)((char *)&foo + 1 * sizeof (int [5]) + 2 * sizeof (int))

&bar[1][2] == (int *)((char *)bar[1] + 2 * sizeof (int)) // no & before bar!
           == (int *)((char *)*(int **)((char *)&bar + 1 * sizeof (int *))
                      + 2 * sizeof (int))
```

Answer (score 3):

`int foo[5][4];`

`foo` is not an array of pointers; it's an array of arrays. Below image will help.

[image]

Comment: this is what OP was asking about