# Pass a column of 2D array

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a `2D array` and I want to pass it's *i* th column to a `sort function` that takes in a `1D array` and sorts it.
Can it be done without copying the column to another `array` in `C/C++` language. I am concerned about reducing `time and space` used. (Ofcourse the *complexity* remains same)

Comment: I think you should be able to. Just pass the 2D array to the function. But likely you will need to write your own sort function, rather than using the generic `sort` or `qsort`.

Comment: @rcs The actual problem is quite simple to solve. In my case I just want to discover whether it can be done in the setting I have given rather than just solving the problem.

Comment: Well, if you interpret you first index as column index (a[m][n] - n-th column from m-th row), then you can just pass a[m]. If talking about C++ you can use vector of vectors and don't worry about having to pass length of a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that by `sort` you mean `std::sort` from STL, which takes random access iterators. So all you need to do is provide column iterators.

You can either implement one by yourself ([example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/)), use some iterator library (ie. [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html)) or use some matrix implementation which provides row/column iterators.

Answer (score 2):

If you can write your own sort function, it's rather easy; you just make the interface like this:

```
void Sort (T a [], size_t n,  size_t stride);
```

The key is in the `stride` parameter, which is the distance between the elements of this "virtual" array. For example, if you have a `float x [10][20];` and you want to send its column #2, you'd do this: (some casts omitted for clarity)

```
Sort (x[0] + 2, 10, 20); // Usually, stride is the width of the 2D array
```

Inside the `Sort` function, you access the `i`th element of an array that has a stride like this:

```
a[i * stride] = 42;
```

That's it.

You can use the same principle to write your own `MatrixColumnView` class that wraps up this concept and can be passed into templated functions that take arrays.

If you want to work with STL or STL-like libraries, you can simply write your own `MatrixColumnIterator` iterator class that essentially uses an stride internally and gives iteration over a column of a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the multidimensional array storage in C/C++ is actually a 1D-arrary,

which you can refer a very good explanation in this post : [How to get column of a multidimensional array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258084/how-to-get-column-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-c-c)

Therefore I do not think there's any default / easy method to extract a particular column of a 2D array and pass it to another function.

Comment: Ok, so I discover that it cannot be done as explained in the post you referred.

Comment: as Johny wrote - providing proper iterators would suffice. Iterators in C++ world is a most common structure, so I wouldn't say there is no 'easy' way

Comment: I agree with you and I upvote @Johny 's answer as well :)
What I was thinking is that it is quite hard for me to pass a column directly to a his_own_sort(), without using external library or preprocessing...