# How to pass a column of a selected range

Tags: vba, excel

I did a little research and I found [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036496/pass-a-column-of-2d-array).  The problem is it is written for some language called C that I am not familiar with.  Not that I am all that familiar with VBA either but that is what I am working in and doing a very nice job of screwing things up.  So in an effort to thwart my abilities to screw things up and instead make things work, how do I pass a sub range or column from a user selected column?

so in my example code I was trying to pass the entire first column of whatever was selected.  Lets say user range was B34:D40, I want to pass B34:B40 such that arrange is B34:B40.

```
Sub initialsub (userrange as range)

Call secondfunction (userrange([],1)

end sub
----------------------------------------------------------------
function secondfunction (arrange as range) as long

some function that counts a variety of things in a single column

secondfunction = 45

end function
```

Comment: hmm. So if range is `A10:B20`, you want `A10:A20`?

Comment: correct!  or if the user selected B34:D50, I want to pass in the call either through another variable, a function, or syntax B34:B50.  I just got rid of using the A column since it is column 1 in absolute reference as well as relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim FirstColumn As Range

    Set FirstColumn = Intersect(Selection(1).EntireColumn, Selection)
    MsgBox FirstColumn.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Also:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Selection.Columns(1).Address
End Sub
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: is there a way without using selection?  Right now I am testing the code by calling it from a sub and passing it a hard coded range.  There for with my test sub there is no selection made.  I do like this method when an actual selection is available.  And I do agree this is exactly what I stated in the title of the question!

Comment: would `intersect(userrange(1).entirecolumn,userrange)` if I was passing B34:D40 as userrange?  Would the intersect result in B34:B40?

Comment: Good point about the block style range...but since that is my case THIS TIME, I will be selfish and accept this as the answer. 8)  What happens if you just used `userrange(1).entirecolumn`  would it return the entire column of just the urserrange or will it take the entire column of the worksheet?

Comment: @ForwardEd  It would return the entire column, but..................see my little edit.

Comment: hrrmmm so if I have to pass the range, would I use `userrange.Columns(1).address` or `userrange.columns(1)` in the function call?

Comment: @ForwardEd  Since you want to do stuff with the individual cells in that first column, I personally would pass `userrange.Columns(1).Cells` ............this will insure that Excel treats it as a Range Object rather than a Columns Object.

Comment: `.cells` is definitely the key.  I tried address.  that blew up on me and gave an error on type mismatch.  I tried just `.column(1)`, and that did not give an error, but it also did not give the right results!  Thanks for the help on this one Gary.