# Can I use pointer to print out arrays of int array just like arrays of string?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I want to print out array of string like:

```
char juices_A[][12] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
```

I can simply use `juices_A[0]`,`juices_A[1]`,`juices_A[3]`, respectively as a pointer to string `"dragonfruit"`, `"waterberry"`, `"sharonfruit"`, and print them out.

But what if I want to print out array of int array like:

```
int data[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

I can not simply use `data[0]`,`data[1]`,`data[2]` as pointer to `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, `{ 4, 5, 6 }`, `{ 7, 8, 9 }`, I need to adopt a more complicated way to print them out. I need to use loop inside loop. So I want to know why I can not use pointer in the int situation? I read on book "**Array variables are like pointers..**" so I assume int array variable `data[0],data[1],data[2]` are also like pointers...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i_A = 0;
    char juices_A[][12] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    for (; i_A < 3; i_A++)
        printf("%s;", juices_A[i_A]);
    puts("");

    int i_B = 0;
    int data[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    for (; i_B < 3; i_B++) {
        int i_C = 0;
        for (; i_C < 3; i_C++)
            printf("%i,", data[i_B][i_C]);
        printf(";");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the result is:

```
dragonfruit;waterberry;sharonfruit;
1,2,3,;4,5,6,;7,8,9,;
```

Comment: The language treats `char*` as a string -- an array of characters that has a terminating null character. There is nothing of the sort for `int` and `int*`. `char` and `char*` are special in that regard.

Comment: You seem to understand things pretty clearly, and with reference to the above comment too, the simple answer is 'no'.

Comment: BTW, your example refers to `juice_A[0]` when your array is called `juices_A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use access arrays like pointers and vice versa.

Here's the output from the program below:

```
dragonfruit;waterberry;sharonfruit;
{ { 1, 2, 3, }, { 4, 5, 6, }, { 7, 8, 9, }, }
```

Here's a modification to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW_WIDTH 3
#define TABLE_HEIGHT 3
int main(void) {

    char *juices[] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", };
    int data[TABLE_HEIGHT][ROW_WIDTH] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

    for (int n = 0; n < ROW_WIDTH; n++) 
        printf("%s;", juices[n]);

    int *ip = (int *)data;

    printf("\n{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_HEIGHT; i++) {
       printf("{ ");
       for(int j = 0; j < ROW_WIDTH; j++) {
           printf("%d, ", *ip + ((i * ROW_WIDTH) + j));
       }
       printf("}, ");
    }
    printf("}\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with using pointer notation is you lose the sense of boundaries that the [] notation maintains for you.  So in this example we just treat data like a single dimension array of ints that we have a pointer to, and then use basic matrix math to represent it as an H x W table.  And C knows, that, because it is a pointer to an int array that it needs to move use internal pointer offset by 4-bytes for each 'external' increment of 1.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2, `in this example we just treat data like a single dimension array of ints that we have a pointer to ...` in practice it works, but it's undefined behavior, take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25303647/1606345) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7785116/1606345)

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd answer is easier to understand, as it's my bed time.  I was toying with casting data as a **, but as it's late I didn't pursue that further.  I wasn't aware of the caveat about optimizing compilers.  I'd really be surprised if there's a C compiler that would break for cases like this because so many people depend on predictable layout of data.  And while there is a specification - we all know the pressure vendors and the community feel to succumb to the popular demand and tolerate things that are not technically what they initially intended :-) Keith's answer is excellent tho.

Comment: @AlterMann - And thanks for keeping me honest. I will have to re-visit your quoted text again and try to make sense of it.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2, you're welcome,  `I'd really be surprised if there's a C compiler that would break for cases like this`, as pointed out by Ken Thompson in comments, it's safe enough because most C implementations don't do array bounds-checking, but the correct way of dealing with that array through a pointer is using `int (*ip)[ROW_WIDTH] = data;`

Answer (score 1):

**Strings:**

```
-------------------------
|h | e | l | l | o | \0 |
-------------------------
|w | o | r | l | d | \0 |
------------------------
```

As you see this array can be stored in a 2D char array

```
char a[2][6];
```

Now `a[i]` gives the starting address of each row and `%s` prints out a string until a `\0` is enountered so you can just pass the address of each row and get the contents of the row. Just like

```
char *p = "hello";
printf("%s\n",p);
```

**Note:**
Again if you want to read the character at a particular location you need to specify `a[row][col]`

Whereas

**Integers:**

```
----------------
|1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
----------------
|5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
----------------
```

Now you can have a array like

```
int b[2][4];
```

`b[i]` will give you the starting address of each row but in order to get the value stored in a particular location you need to specify value with `b[row][col]`.

The difference is the sentinel condition for valid C strings is `\0` and is it being used to access each row which is not the case for integers.

> so I assume int array variable data[0],data[1],data[2] are also like
>   pointers

Yes they are pointers to each row but you need to dereference the pointer to get the value right? So if `data[0]` is a pointer then do `data[0][column]`

Answer (score 1):

The `char juices_A[][12] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit" };` whenever the data is accessed it prints till `\0` is reached, as strings are considered only till `\0`. So when we use `juices_A[0]` it points to start of first data till `\0` is reached.But to get an individual char we need to mention both the dimensions of the array.

`char juices_A[1][2]` to access `'t'` in `waterberry`

But this is not the case with `int` as each is considered as separate entity. So we use both dimensions of the array to access it.

Even if we reduce the size of the array like `char juices_A[][12] = { "dragon", "waterberry", "sharonfruit" };` when printed it outputs

`dragon;waterberry;sharonfruit`

But in the case of `int data[3][3] = { { 1, 2}, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };` it outputs

1,2,**0**,....` 
this makes the difference

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int data[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int *ptr;
    int lines = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    int i;


    ptr = &data[0][0];

    while (lines-- > 0) {
        i = columns;

        while (i-- > 0) {
            printf("%d ", *ptr);
            ptr += 1;
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int data[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int *ptr;
    int lines = 3;
    int columns = 3;
    int max = lines * columns;


    ptr = &data[0][0];

    while (max-- > 0) {
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
        ptr++;

        if (max % columns == 0)
            putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```