# Transfering a 2-dimensional array into a single dimension array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I'm trying to make a program in C that transfers a 2-dimensions-array(a matrix to be particular) into a single-dimension-array. For example, if we have a matrix with L lines and C columns, it should turn into a a single line newL=L*C. Therefore, if the matrix has 3 lines and 4 columns, the new array will have 3*4=12 as its size.

> The matrix should turn to this:

```
1 2
     --> 1 2 3 4
3 4
```

The problem I'm facing right now, is how to assign the matrix to the array without having random values or repeated values.

> The piece of code I'm concerned with, goes like this:

```
for(k=1;k<=t;k++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
            {
                v[k]=m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

k,i and j are counters of the matrix(2-dimensions-array) and the the array. two of which; i and j, are counters for the matrix and k is the array's counter. Notice that each one of them starts from 1 and goes to its size and in this size I will use 2 lines and 2 columns for the matrix therefore the array will have a size of 4(2*2).

- l is the number of lines in the array.
- c is the number of colunms in the array.
- t is the size of the array. t=l*c

> Executing the code gives me this as a return:

```
1 2
    --> 4 4 4 4
3 4
```

> Simply said, the piece of code will ALWAYS give the last value of the matrix to the array. So if I replace 4 with 5 in the matrix, the array will have 5 5 5 5.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full code to understand what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int c,i,j,l,k,t;
    printf("Donner le nombres des lignes: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    printf("Donner le nombres des colonnes: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    int m[l][c];
    t=l*c;
    int v[t];
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("Donner m[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    for(k=1;k<=t;k++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
            {
                v[k]=m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(k=0;k<t;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",v[k]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

**Thank you guys for the help, I found the correct way to do it.**

Comment: Do not use letters which can easily be confused with digits! Here, I assume you mean the letter `l` (lower case "ell").

Comment: @Olaf it's a bad habbit. You told me that yesterday and I still use it. Sorry. Yes, I mean lower case L with l.

Comment: Get rid of that Hobbit - ehm habit - asap. The longer you keep it, the harder it will become. Also get rid of indexing arrays from `1`. Most programming languages use zero-based array-indexes. Anything else just confuses and may keep the compiler from optimizing the program.

Comment: Dont edit saying you found the correct way to do it! Mark one of the answers correct, or if you found a better way add your own answer!

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the tip, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need not the outer loop
2. Array indices are zero-based in C

Thus, we have:

```
    for(k = 0, i = 0; i < o; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < p; j++)
        {
            v[k++] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
```

where `o` and `p` - dimensions of the matrix `m`

Answer (score 1):

If we have a multidimensional array like this:

```
int nums[3][3];
```

And we have:

```
int all[9];
```

And we've got:

```
int a, b;
```

We'll reference each of the nums like this:

```
nums[a][b];
```

Now think of what the values of a and b will actually be:

```
for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
   for (b = 0; b < 3; b++)
      all[((a * 3) + b)] = nums[a][b];
}
```

This will work so long as you multiply a with the number of elements it will iterate:

```
int nums[5][5];
int all[25];

int a, b;

for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        all[((a * 5) + b)] = nums[a][b];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention your question is "how to I fix the code?" I think plenty of people have given you the correct answer. This is your code along with the corrected code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int c,i,j,l,k,t;
    printf("Donner le nombres des lignes: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    printf("Donner le nombres des colonnes: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    int m[l][c];
    t=l*c;
    int v[t];
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("Donner m[%d][%d]: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n");

    /* corrected code below */
    k = 0;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            v[k]=m[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    /* corrected code above */

    for(k=0;k<t;k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",v[k]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I replied to a guy named Ben that it worked, forgot to edit. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for(k=1;k<=t;k++)
   for(i=1;i<=l;i++)
      for(j=1;j<=c;j++)
          v[k]=m[i][j];
```

does not do what you think. Think about when you first loop through the `j`  part, you will be setting all the `0th` element of v the entire time, finally the last value you set will stick (ie, the one in position `1, 1` which happens to be `4`). Then you will increment `k` to `1` and repeat it again, resulting in all `4's`.  You want this:

```
 for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
     for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
         v[i*l+j] = m[i][j]; // i*l + j gives you the equivelent position in a 1D vector.
```

Make sure your `v` vector is the right size ie. `int v[l*c];`. Also remember that in `c` zero indexing is used.If you really do need 1 based indexing (which you dont ...) then do this:

```
int k = 1;
  for(i = 1; i <= l; i++)
     for(j = 1; j <= c; j++)
         v[k++]=m[i][j];
```

But remember that this will make any further operations on this vector **Gross**. So dont do this ....

Comment: Your code uses `k` in the assignment line but never declares it.

Comment: But I still need a FOR for the array to fill each frame.

Comment: @Amine I dont know what you mean by that.

Comment: i and j will start with i, implying L equals 2. the new array will fill the frame 1*2+1 first then 2*2+2 and so on.. it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, they are the same, you just change where the loop stops. if you start with 0 then i stops before L (i<l) but if you start with 1 then i stopts at L (i<=L). Right?

Comment: @Ben I siwtched to 0 indexing and used a while for display instead of for. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the new array is the correct size, something like the following should work:

```
k=0;
for(i=0;i<l;i++){
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        v[k]=m[i][j];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Essentially, you are traversing over the matrix (your lines and columns--as you put it) and at the same time increasing the position (k) in the new array where you want that value to be put.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the matrix elements as a single dimension array, you could declare an `int` pointer `v`:

```
int m[3][4];
int *v = (int*)m;
// then access for example m[1][1] as v[5]
```

Or, to actually copy the array, use a double `for` (as in the other answers), a single `for` like below

```
int vv[12];
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    vv[i] = m[i/4][i%4];
```

or just use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(vv, m, 12*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: No way! You have no garuntee that `m` is stored in continuous memory! `v[5]` is undefined behaviour~

Comment: @Ben You're wrong, look for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784758/c-c-multidimensional-array-internals or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory