# How Physically are Arrays Stored (Specifically with dimensions greater than 2)?

Tags: c++, arrays

### What I Know

I know that arrays `int ary[]` can be expressed in the equivalent "pointer-to" format: `int* ary`. However, what I would like to know is that if these two are the same, how physically are arrays stored?

I used to think that the elements are stored next to each other in the ram like so for the array `ary`:

```
int size = 5;
int* ary = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { ary[i] = i; }
```

This (I believe) is stored in RAM like: `...[0][1][2][3][4]...`

This means we can subsequently replace `ary[i]` with `*(ary + i)` by just increment the pointers' location by the index.

### The Issue

The issue comes in when I am to define a 2D array in the same way:

```
int width = 2, height = 2;
Vector** array2D = new Vector*[height]
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    array2D[i] = new Vector[height];
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) { array2D[i][j] = (i, j); }
}
```

Given the class `Vector` is for me to store both x, and y in a single fundamental unit: (x, y).

So how exactly would the above be stored?

1. It cannot logically be stored like `...[(0, 0)][(1, 0)][(0, 1)][(1, 1)]...` as this would mean that the `(1, 0)`th element is the same as the `(0, 1)`th.
2. It cannot also be stored in a 2d array like below, as the physical RAM is a single 1d array of 8 bit numbers:

   - `...[(0, 0)][(1, 0)]...`
   - `...[(0, 1)][(1, 1)]...`
3. Neither can it be stored like `...[&(0, 0)][&(1, 0)][&(0, 1)][&(1, 1)]...`, given `&(x, y)` is a pointer to the location of `(x, y)`. This would just mean each memory location would just point to another one, and the value could not be stored anywhere.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You have not defined a 2D array in the second case. You have defined an array of arrays. You wind up with one array of pointers to `height` other arrays. All of the arrays could be anywhere in memory.

Comment: The first paragraph of "What I know" is wrong

Comment: `new` allocates a block of contiguous storage. Count the number of calls to `new` in your code to see how many blocks of storage you have.

Comment: or you could use search and find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14646919/4440694) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7784790/4440694)

Comment: Those are great, @sfk92fksdf but don't apply to a dynamically allocated array of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP is struggling with a dynamically allocated array of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays. Each of these allocations is its own block of memory sitting somewhere in storage. There is no connection between them other than the logical connection established by the pointers in the outer array.

To try to visualize this say we make

```
int ** twodee;
twodee = new int*[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    twodee[i] = new int[4];
}
```

and then

```
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        twodee[i][j] = count++;
    }
}
```

so we should wind up with `twodee` looking something like

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

right?

Logically, yes. But laid out in memory `twodee` might look something like this batsmurph crazy mess:

[image: batsmurph crazy mess]

You can't really predict where your memory will be, you're at the mercy of the whatever memory manager handles the allocations and what already in storage where it might have been efficient for your memory to go. This makes laying dynamically-allocated multi-dimensional arrays out in your head almost a waste of time.

And there are a whole lot of things wrong with this when you get down into the guts of what a modern CPU can do for you. The CPU has to hop around a lot, and when it's hopping, it's ability to predict and preload the cache with memory you're likely to need in the near future is compromised. This means your gigahertz computer has to sit around and wait on your megahertz RAM a lot more than it should have to.

Try to avoid this whenever possible by allocating single, contiguous blocks of memory. You may pick up a bit of extra code mapping one dimensional memory over to other dimensions, but you don't lose any CPU time. C++ will have generated all of that mapping math for you as soon as you compiled `[i][j]` anyway.

Comment: So would it be faster to declare a 1d array, identifying each element as (j * width + i), such that it is a continuous block, but calculating the location for each element will take longer?

Comment: Very little longer. Resolving p[i][j] is either a couple of adds and a multiply or a couple of adds and a pointer dereference by the time the compiler is done with it. If you have the pointer dereference and the other side is not cached, that's where you get punished. With the 1D array, the next row is likely already loaded and cached.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is:  It is compiler dependent.

A more helpful answer (I hope) is that you can create 2D arrays that are layed out directly in memory, or you can create "2D arrays" that are actually 1D arrays, some with data, some with pointers to arrays.

There is a convention that the compiler is happy to generate the right kind of code to dereference and/or calculate the address of an element within an array when you use brackets to access an element in the array.

Generally arrays that are known to be 2D at compile time (eg int array2D[a][b]) will be layed out in memory without extra pointers and the compiler knows to multiply AND add to get an address each time there is an access.  If your compiler isn't good at optimizing out the multiply, it makes repeated accesses much slower than they can be, so in the old days we often did pointer math ourselves to avoid the multiply if possible.

There is the issue that a compiler might optimize by rounding the lower dimension size up to a power of two, so a shift can be used instead of multiply, which would then require padding the locations (then even though they are all in one memory block, there are meaningless holes).

(Also, I'm pretty sure I've run into the problem that within a procedure, it needs to know which way the 2D array really is, so you may need to declare parameters in a way that lets the compiler know how to code the procedure, eg a[][] is different from *a[]).  And obviously you can actually get the pointer from the array of pointers, if that is what you want--which isn't the same thing as the array it points too, of course.

In your code, you have clearly declared a full set of the lower dimension 1D arrays (inside the loop), and you have ALSO declared another 1D array of pointers you use to get to each one without a mulitply--instead by a dereference.  So all those things will be in memory.  Each 1D array will surely be sequentially layed out in a contiguous block of memory.  It is just that it is entirely up to the memory manager as to where those 1D arrays are, relative to each other.  (I doubt a compiler is smart enough to actually do the "new" ops at compile time, but it is theoretically possible, and would obviously affect/control the behavior if it did.)

Using the extra array of pointers clearly avoids the multiply ever and always.  But it takes more space, and for sequential access actually makes the accesses slower and bigger (the extra dereference) versus maintaining a single pointer and one dereference.

Even if the 1D arrays DO end up contiguous sometimes, you might break it with another thread using the same memory manager, running a "new" while your "new" inside the loop is repeating.